# Remove interior paint from carpet

Tags: painting, paint, carpet, interior, paint-removal

I recently wanted to repaint an interior wall. I took many precautions to cover the carpet using tarps, tape, and newspaper. Despite all of that, I still managed to get paint onto the carpets and didn't notice until it had already dried.

I've been googling and all I can see are guides to remove the art-types of  paints from carpets (acrylic, latex, and water-based), which I assume is probably ill fated for me because I used a paint + primer that I got from walmart.

Is there any way to remove this paint without damaging the carpet any further?

Comment: Your paint you got from Walmart was almost certainly latex based (but check the can) so use some of those tips you found but take seriously the advice from Ben in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carpets and paints can be made from a variety of materials. Water might clean it up. Paint thinners might dissolve the carpet (depending on the carpet). You could try isopropyl alcohol without much risk. But I would start by testing some carpet fibers (cut a few fibers off with some scissors) in a dish of paint thinner before testing thinner on the carpet. And still, even if the fibers look okay, use caution applying thinner to carpet. Apply thinner to a rag instead, and wipe the paint off with the rag.

If thinner dissoves the carpet, then the last resort is to give the carpet a trim. Hopefully the paint is not too deep and you can carefully cut out just the paint.

Comment: It may be worth contacting a pro, I spilt modelling paint and a professional got it out. Further to this I have seen some carpet repair companies that can thread in patches of spare or similar carpet or cut out a patch from somewhere like a robe or closet to swap with a stained/damaged section. Looks like it was never there.